# twitter bootstrap drop down menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a drop down menu using **twitter bootstrap**. my current navigation is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs " style="width: 860px;">
<li >
    <a href="#" >Employees</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a href="#" >Projects</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a href="#" >Clients</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a href="#" >Assign Projects</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a href="#" > Reports</a>

</li>
<li><a href="logout.php" >Logout</a></li>
```

here I want a drop down menu for **Reports** link

Comment: BS docs is quite clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boostrap already have that http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns

```
<div class="dropdown">
<!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->
<a href="#">Drop me!</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See that example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrV6u/

And include to your page this scripts:

[jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js)

[Bootstrap Dropdown Plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js)

Comment: thanks for your effort but its still not showing drop down menu and if i assume that there is some js problem, error console is also not showing any error :(

Comment: you probably forgot to icnlude jQuery library and twitter-bootstrap dropdown plugin

Comment: This example toggle dropdown on click by item. For example on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/jrV6u/1/

Comment: well there is some thing wrong with my project, this one is also not working :(

Comment: sorry that was not browser problem, problem is in the project :(